# Pass input value to AJAX request in React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am using Github Search API for people to be able to search for repositories on github. I'm using React and am quite new to all of this. 
I want to pass the input value to the AJAX request so it only requests that repository with the specific name. Is there a way to use React to pass the input value?

```
 class SearchBox extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onKeyUp = this.onKeyUp.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}



render() {
    return(
        <form>
            <input type="text" className="searchbox" onChange={this.onChange} onKeyUp={this.onKeyUp} />
              <ul className="suggestions">
        <li>Filter for a city</li>
        <li>or a state</li>
    </ul>
        </form>
    );
}

  onChange(event) {
        const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, repositories);
const html = matchArray.map(place => {
    const regex = new RegExp(this.value, "gi");
    const cityName = place.city.replace(regex, `<span className="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
    const stateName = place.state.replace(regex, `<span className="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
    return `
  <li>
  <span className="name">${cityName}, ${stateName}</span>

  </li>
  `;
}).join('');
console.log(matchArray);


}

onKeyUp(event) {
        const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, repositories);
const html = matchArray.map(place => {
    const regex = new RegExp(this.value, "gi");
    const cityName = place.name.replace(regex, `<span className="hl">${this.value}</span>`);

    return `
  <li>
  <span class="nameName">${cityName}, </span>

  </li>
  `;
}).join('');
console.log(matchArray);


}
}

ReactDOM.render(
<SearchBox />,
document.getElementById("searching")
);
```

JS

```
const endpoint = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?sort=stars&order=desc&q=' + searchTerm;
const repositories = [];

fetch(endpoint)
.then(blob => blob.json())
.then(data => repositories.push(...data));

function findMatches(wordToMatch, repositories) {
return repositories.filter(place => {

    const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, "gi");
    return place.city.match(regex) || place.state.match(regex);
});
};
```

So as you can see I want to pass the input value into a variable called searchTerm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) attribute to a DOM element you would like to get reference to. Then you can refer to that element in your react component.

In your case you can add `ref` to the search box as follows

```
<input type="text" ref={(input) => { this.searchBox = input; }} className="searchbox" ... />
```

and then refer to it's value in your react component as `this.searchBox.value`.

Beart in mind that if you are using react state to manage your app's state you will need to put your fetch request in the component. If you do not want to do this I suggest you to look at [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) or [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) for your app's state management.

**Edit**

Based on your comment I created a codepen to illustrate how one could refer to the value of the input field using a `ref` attribute http://codepen.io/DeividasK/pen/PpZpNL.

Comment: to be completely honest, I don't understand what you mean. When I try this I get an error message saying that value is undefined.

Comment: @Naomi I have updated my answer to include a working example.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question though. It's not passing the variable to an AJAX request.

Comment: @Naomi Once you get that value, you can make your request as required. Say in the `onKeyUp`  or `onChange` function. I was not sure when do you want that function to run, so I did not add this in the example.